# Django filter update specific field based on ajax return

Tags: django, django-models, django-ajax-selects

I have a ajax post that returns the following data:

```
{u'related_id': u'9', u'db_name': u'my_field', u'name': u'jsaving_draft', u'value': u'hypothesis sadfasdfadfws asdfasdf'}
```

In my view I have:

```
if request.is_ajax():                                                                                                                   
     if "jsaving_draft" in request.body:                                                                                                 
         results = json.loads(request.body)                                                                                              
         print results                                                                                                                   
         save_id = results['related_id']                                                                                                 
         save_db = results['db_name']                                                                                                    
         save_value = results['value']
         temp = Dbtable.objects.filter(id=save_id).update(save_db=save_value)
```

How can I specify the specific table element to update based on save_db without hardcoding the database row name. I have a table in my database named.

I tried doing something like like:

```
Dbtable.objects.filter(id=save_id).update("%s"=save_value) % save_db
```

but that failed spectacularly. Does anyone have an idea of how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use keyword argument unpacking:

```
Dbtable.objects.filter(id=save_id).update(**{save_db: save_value})
```

Example:

```
>>> def test(a,b):
...     return a + b
... 
>>> test(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})
3
```

Comment: Dude! You are my hero! I have to wait 8 min to mark this as the solution. I look all over the docs and did not see this. Where/how the hell did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @user1462141 sure, please see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists) and these threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769403/understanding-kwargs-in-python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs.